# We denote by $a,b,c$ the sides of a triangle whose vertices were chosen from the vertices of a regular pentagon. Calculate $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, products

**PROBLEM**

We denote by $a,b,c$ the lengths of the sides of a triangle whose vertices were randomly chosen from among the vertices of a regular pentagon.
Calculate $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$.

**WHAT I THOUGHT OF**

First of all: the drawing

[image]

I don't really understand the requirment. If we chose the 3 vertices to be $A,B,C$, as $AB=BC$ (because ABCDE is a regular pentagon) we will have the product $0$, becuase one of the terms will be $AB-BC=0$.

Does i understand the requirment wrong or something? Hope one of you can help me!

Comment: please indicate the source of the problem, with a link if possible. One possibility is that we   correct the question. Another is that we find material in the surrounding pages that explains.

Comment: or this is meant to illustrate the pigeonhole principle:  two of the sides could be edges, or two  of the sides diagonals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on correct path.

**Steps :**

1. Show that all diagonals of a regular pentagon are of same length.
2. Only two types of triangles can be formed. If each side has length $x$ and each diagonal has length $d$, the two triangles have side-lengths
   $$x,\, x,\,d \quad \quad or \quad \quad d,\, d,\, x$$
   [image]

Thus any triangle formed is **isosceles** and $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a) = \ldots \,?$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!